# No ads show up with Real admob ad Unit Id

Tags: android, admob

I have tried adding Admob ad to my app.When i use actual Ad unit Id no banner ad show up at the bottom in the layout. I had made Ad unit Id on 19 th june.Test Ads do show up in the layout when i use sample ad unit id.
Let me know if you need any other info.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, actualAppId);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("1FC8C6E02CD016F49544EADF9599F3FD")
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please share the java and xml code where you applied the add.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add test device id if you are testing Ads even with real Ad unit Id. Device id will appear in logcat when you run app.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
     .build();
```

Comment: added test device but still no ads show up with real ad unit id

Comment: The problem may be with your ad unit id. but if it is correct then try adding listener on AdView and override onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) then see the error code. It will definitely help you.

Comment: I needed to enter the billing information. That solved the problem